# DHCP сервер не прописывает DNS для Linux-машин

Tags: dhcp, dns, linux

DHCP на Windows server 2008r2. Есть необходимость получать доступ по имени к виртуальным машинам с Asp Linux 11.2 (ядро 2.6.17). Но DHCP не определяет их имена, причем для всех линукс машин, Debian 5 тоже не работает. Виндовс машины работают корректно. Что не хватает на линукс машинах в целом, а главное как подключить старую ASP Linux?

Answer (score 1):

DHCP и не занимается определением имен - для этой цели есть DNS. DHCP только осуществляет раздачу адресов в локальной сети и указание какой использовать DNS и WINS.
1)Домен в имени Линух-машин должен быть аналогичен домену Виндоуз-машин.
2)Каким образом настроена виртуализация и, в частности, ее сеть?
3)Проверить получают ли адреса виртуальные машины с Линукс по DHCP
4)Как вариант решения - прописать на DHCP закрепление адресов для линукс-машин
5)Используется ли DNS и как? Если используется свой - прописать виртуалки "в там".
И погуглите на тему "ввод linux-машин в домен windows"

Comment: 1. ok2. Bridge3. Получают4. Слишком много машин5. К сожалению, настраивал не я6. За keyword спасибо

Comment: >2. Bridge  С предоставленным собственным адресом для виртуалки? Если нет - то в этом может гнездиться проблема.   4. - не долго, если использовать автоматизацию. Кажется краем глаза видел инфу, что через PowerShell можно настраивать DHCP - посмотрите, погуглите - возможно, удастся применить, т.к. список-то этих хостов у Вас есть :)  6. - да не за что. Еще есть отличная книга "Линукс-сервер в виндоуз окружении" Стаханова Алексея (немного устарела, но по ней я все сделал для своего 2-го компа на работе - RFR16.1)

Comment: Еще забыл. Поскольку DHCP передает инфу (адрес, адрес DNS) любому компу фактически в "голом" виде, то не получать его линукс-машины не могут. Значит нужно в терминале набрать >cat /etc/resolv.conf  Вывод данной команды даст нам доменное имя и переданные для использования DNS адреса

Comment: [Нашел по поводу PowerShell](http://isazonov.wordpress.com/2013/08/10/powershell-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B5/)  Там описывается резервирование между 2-мя DHCP, но думаю труда не составит изменить под Ваши задачи